# Simple way to save multiple images in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to take photos, and put each images in imageviews. Now i'm doing like below

```
imageView[0] = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView[1] = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
imageView[2] = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
...
```

but i have to use many images, so i want to make the code simpler. Is there any way like using for() or array?

Comment: You can use RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

it is right way to use. But if you asked what is right way to store images
Use Image view binding, that's makes referring them easy.
Add below code in build.gradle

```
 buildFeatures {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    viewBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

add the above code in android below buildtypes

```
binding.imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_myimage));
```

you can change resources as stated in above code